# Can Divine Soul Sorcerer transfer spells to a Warlock's Book of Ancient Secrets?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, sorcerer, rituals

My party has two spellcasters - Tabaxi Divine Soul Sorcerer (me) with proficiency in Arcana (so he can create scrolls) and Tiefling Pact of the Tome Warlock with the Book of Ancient Secrets invocation; this allows him to write down any ritual spells he comes across and cast them as rituals.

Can my Sorcerer write down ritual spells, known to him, into a scroll for the Warlock to transcribe into the Book of Ancient Secrets?

Is there a difference between spells from Sorcerer and Cleric spell list?

Additionally, my Sorcerer has the Magic Initiate feat with which he gains Find Familiar (from Wizard spell list) spell - can he write down that too?

The core question is: are there ways to transfer spells from Sorcerer to Warlock, in this case?  Can the scroll creation be skipped entirely?  Maybe both characters can work together, in some way?

Comment: Welcome! Could you make it clear what is the focus of your question? Is it whether you can *scribe* the various spells into scrolls or whether the warlock can write them into their book?

Comment: "Is there a difference between spells from Sorcerer and Cleric spell list?" That doesn't belong with the rest of the question.  (Suggest you review the section in the book about Divine Soul Sorcerers again, it's pretty clear how those spells work).  Please ask that question separately if it is still unclear after a review.  *Also, this part at the end Can the scroll creation be skipped entirely? Maybe both characters can work together, in some way?* is a separate question.  Please ask that separately with a link to this question.

Comment: Goodness, where are my manners?  Welcome to RPG.SE.  Please take the [tour] to get a feel for how Q&A sites work best, and visit the link on [how to ask a question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) at the [help].  Yes, there is a bit of an art to asking a well scoped question on this site, as I had to discover when I first joined in.